# What is the code generator for computed goto?

Tags: compilation, compiler-construction

example of computed goto:

```
       ...
     GO TO ( 10, 20, 30, 40 ), N
       ... 
10   CONTINUE 
       ... 
20   CONTINUE 
       ... 
40   CONTINUE
```

If N equals one, then go to 10.
If N equals two, then go to 20.
If N equals three, then go to 30.
If N equals four, then go to 40.

What is the code generator of goto in the final state of compiling?

Answer (score 0):

The most common way of compiling computed goto is a static jump table and an indirect branch instruction. For example (without -fPIC):

```
int test(int num) {
const void * const labels[] = {&&a, &&b, &&cl};

goto *labels[num];
a: return 1;
b: return 2;
cl: return 3;
```

}

Is going to be compiled as:

```
    test(int):                               # @test(int)
        movsxd  rax, edi
        jmp     qword ptr [8*rax + .L__const.test(int).labels]
.Ltmp0:                                 # Block address taken
        mov     eax, 1
        ret
.Ltmp1:                                 # Block address taken
        mov     eax, 3
        ret
.Ltmp2:                                 # Block address taken
        mov     eax, 2
        ret
.L__const.test(int).labels:
        .quad   .Ltmp0
        .quad   .Ltmp2
        .quad   .Ltmp1
```